# Lock multiple cells in multiple sheets in one go

Tags: excel

I know how to lock and protect selected cells in a sheet. But are there any way to do it in one sheet, and then it counts for all the sheets. I want to lock the selected yellow cells, in all the sheets.

[image: Image 1]

Comment: When you open a new workbook/sheet **all the cells are locked**.  If you're going to protect the sheet then you have to unlock the cells to allow user interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in one go using the UI:

- Select all the sheets (shift-click on the tabs)
- Select the range on one sheet (which selects it on all the selected sheets)
- lock the cells (this does the same for all selected cells)

Unfortunately the VBA `Range` object does not support "3D ranges" spanning multiple sheets so your options within code are:

- loop over the sheets and set the `Locked` property of the appropriate range for each sheet
- code the equivalent to the UI version above (using `Select`.  This works as `Selection` *can* include ranges from multiple sheets)

I would always go for the first option in code - using `Selection` is slow and very prone to bugs [see this question for more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).  And I can't think of any reason you would need to do it "in one go" when a loop is readable, fast and reliable.